# Heavy image preloading is hanging script

Tags: javascript, image-processing

im working in an image gallery for a client that has high resolution images (something like 1280x1400px) and actually my script does this:

1. load the first image and display it
2. when the first image is loaded, load all thumbnails for that gallery (200x440px each or something like that)
3. when all thumbnails are loaded start caching all the images (sequentially) from the thumbnails (i mean the complete resolution image), so when user choose the second image on the list, it is already preloaded

The problem is that when the second image from the thumbnail is starting to preload the browser is really slow and feels like is going to hang, seems like is taking too much memory or cpu, i dont really know.

Is there any way for preload it like in parallel? or maybe another way to have a "fast to load" image gallery? I've been thinking about having 2 versions of each image a very low resolution one to use as a placeholder and then load the real image and replace it (i think this is how Google Plus Gallery Works)

My main goal is to have a really really fast gallery because it can be kinda slow when user click an image (each file is 200~300kb)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the technique of [CSS sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) for your thumbnails? That would allow you to have one large image that contains all of your thumbnails.

The approach of preloading all images seems a little heavy-handed (is no-one worrying about bandwidth usage?). For speedy delivery, you could host them using a commercial [CDN (content delivery network)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) instead.

Comment: Very very late answer i know but i was kinda busy, but yes i'm considering moving to a commercial CDN and i think its a great idea the CSS Sprites for the thumbnails! thank you

Answer (score 0):

Provide example of how you're trying to preload the image?
Simplest example of preloading multiple images in parallel would be something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var photos = ["/images/foto1.jpg", "/images/foto2.jpg", "/images/foto3.jpg"];
    var images = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < photos.length; i++)
    {
        images[i] = new Image();
        images[i].src = photos[i];
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Richard Ev gave a good answer. I would like to add one other technique for content delivery that might be helpful, namely spreading resources over multiple subdomains. The best explanation (including limitations etc.) can be found [here](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rtt.html#ParallelizeDownloads), however [this IE link](http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2008/07/21/internet-explorer-8-and-maximum-concurrent-connections.aspx) and [this paper](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/parallel/) are also good reading.

Essentially due to browser limitations that implement old HTTP standards, images don't download in high parallelisation (or any content for that matter - the standard is quantifies open connections), but you can trick the browser into opening more connections by spreading resource delivery over multiple subdomains. As is mentioned in the article, there is an upper limit of such spreading beyond which it actually slows down.

Hope this helps (it may or may not be relevant), or at least teaches you something new.